# Eliminar líneas en blanco bash

Tags: bash, cmd

Quiero eliminar los espacios en blanco que me genera el siguiente script:

```sh
cat /etc/passwd | sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/:.*//g' | cat -e
```

El resultado: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es eliminar las primeras líneas, pues eran comentarios que he borrado con el script pero se quedan como líneas en blanco.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```sh
cat /etc/passwd | sed -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/:.*//g' -e '/^$/d' | cat -e
```

Con la expresión `/^$/` estamos buscando líneas **sin espacios en blanco**.

Si necesitamos hacerlo con líneas que **tienen espacios en blanco** la expresión seria `/^[[:space:]]*$/`.

La **`d`** (delete) al final de la expresión despues de la segunda barra es la sintaxis para suprimir esas lineas que van coincidiendo con la búsqueda de la expresión regular.

Comment: Me ha funcionado muchisimas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Una solución muy simple es usando `grep`:

```
$ grep '\S' /etc/passwd
```

De esta manera, evitas imprimir todo tipo de saltos de línea ademas de que sólo usas un programa.

Otra variante es:

```
$ grep -v "^$" /etc/passwd
```

Donde evitas imprimir lineas vacías.

Otra solución todavía más simple y elegante es:

```
$ awk NF /etc/passwd
```

Donde la variable de `awk` NF (número de campos), se setea cuando tiene líneas no vacías.